# EF 4.1 Code First - Self-referencing foreign keys and Foreign key to other tables

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-4.1

I have a POCO class as follows

```
public class Category 
{ 
   public int ID {get; set; }
   public string desc {get; set; }
   public int parentID {et; set; }
}

public class Issue 
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   ....
   public int categoryID {get; set; }
   public int subCategoryID {get; set; }

   public virtual Category category{get; set; }
   public virtual Category subCategory {get; set;}
}
```

I keep getting errors with foreign keys with the above classes.  Basically, my Category table holds categories with sub categories.  And an issue can have a category and subCategory. Would somebody guide me to the correct way to define this relationship?  I've tried using Foreign Key annotations but it gives me an error saying the data base was created but the object creation failed because of foreign key relation specified on Issue.  Any ideas why?  And what I can do to resolve this ?

Comment: What means subcategory in case of issue - and how category and subCategory properties are related ? For instance if we have some subCategory set for issue - category property must have its parent set ?

Comment: Basically an issue could have a category and a sub-category.  This is represented (or supposed to be) by the Category class. If an object has the parentId populated, it implies that the object represents a subcategory and the parentId it is pointing to is the Category.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this article - [How to Configure a Self Referencing Entity in Code First](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code)

I believe that will help you setup the relationship correctly. As you will see in the article you need to define some addditional fluent settings in the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class.

Comment: Is the Fluent API only required for self-referencing constraints or would you need to add it for all foreign keys?  Thank you

Comment: I believe you only need it for the self-referencing constraints or other conditions that are beyond the standard EF Code First conventions. Typical foreign keys will be configured automatically without the need to add additional conditions in the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: As per article, I changed my classes like so  public class Category { public int ID {get; set; } public string desc {get; set; } public int? parentId {get; set; } public virtual Category parentCategory {get; set;} public virtual ICollection<Issue> issues {get; set; }   In my OnModelCreating() I have put in             modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOptional(c => c.parentCategory).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.parentID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasRequired(i => i.category).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.categoryId);
But I get a 'Cannot determine principal end...' error

Comment: This is the whole error - Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Helpdesk.Domain.Entities.Category_parentCategory' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Comment: I created a sample console app based on this and it worked for me. Please see this gist - https://gist.github.com/1045067 for the code to see if this is what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: Paige,     I restarted my VS session, dropped the database and tried again and it seems to work now for some reason! Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single class.

For EF4.1 Code first I have the following example:

```
/// <summary>
/// represents a single configuration item within CM
/// </summary>
public class CI
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ....

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? Parent_ID { get; set; }




    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    [ForeignKey("Parent_ID")]
    public virtual ICollection<CI> Contents { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("Contents")]
    public virtual CI Parent { get; set; }
```